# Why regular expression (a+)* takes so long when matching against aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab?

Tags: regex, optimization

I’m reading the book Mastering regular expression 3rd edition and I’m completely confused on 6.2.4.1 “Exponential matches”

The example on the book is a little bit more complex, to be more focused, I give an example which is basically the same with the one on the book

Why the matching takes so long, could anyone explain step by step how the matching are executed ? Thanks in advance

**Regular expression:**

`(a+)*`

**Target text:**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

Comment: See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: `(a+)*` `+` means 1 or more times, `*` zero or any times. in this case just use one?

Comment: Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/iZ6kO1/1). I've only used `aaaa` as a test string which already takes 50 steps (`aaaaa` takes over 1500 etc.). Click on "debug regex" and make sure to place a checkmark in the "Disable optimizations" checkbox.

Comment: Also, this regex is not slow on the target text, at least not on my machine.

Comment: @Jerry: It will be slow if you understand "match" to mean "match the entire string" instead of "search for a substring".

Comment: @TimPietzcker Indeed. I take match to match any substring by default, and the entire string only when beginning and end anchors are used, but thinking again now, I guess OP meant the entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why '(a+)*' would be slow on that target.
It should match the substring "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" quickly.

'(a+)*$' however would in many common regexp implementations have problems with "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab".

The reason is something called catastrophic backtracking.

What happens is;

The regexp matching engine starts at the beginning of the regexp, looking for the token 'a' repeated one or more times.  It finds an 'a', so since it's a greedy match it matches all a's to the 'a+'.  It then hits a 'b'.  It now has as the remainder of the string "b" and it has a choice; it can try to make more matches for (a+)* - this fails, or it can match the end of the string, which also fails.  Since both options fails it needs to backtrack, matching all a's except the last.  It now has as the remainder of the string "ab" and the same choice as before, but now it can make another match for (a+)*.  It does so and has as the remainder of the string "b"; leaving it in the position we saw earlier.  So it backtracks so that the remainder of the string is "aab".  Here things starts getting interesting; it will need to try (a)(a) and (aa) before it can give up and backtrack.  When it backtracks it has as the remainder "aaab", leading it to try (aaa), (aa)(a), (a)(aa), and (a)(a)(a) before it can give up and backtrack a further step.

The number of ways that the engine can slice your long sequence of a's grows exponentially in the length of the string, and this is what causes the regexp to be slow.